# numpy array construction with broadcasting

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, array-broadcasting, numpy-ndarray

I would like stack together arrays that have different, but broadcast compatible arrays. Given 7x5, 7x1, 1x5 and 1x1 arrays I want to do something like

```
 a475 = mkarr([a75, a71, a15, a11])
```

where `a455` will be a 4x7x5 array.
Ideally I would also like to be able to do

```
 a2275 = mkarr([[a75, a71], [a15, a11]])
```

to get a 2x2x7x5 array.

What is the most concise way to express these operation in numpy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`np.broadcast_arrays`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_arrays.html):

```
a475 = np.stack(np.broadcast_arrays(a75, a71, a15, a11))
```

Note that this creates views of the original arrays, so it should not entail any extra memory usage.

Comment: FYI: `broadcast_arrays` returns a *list* of arrays.  The arrays in the list are views of the original arrays, but as soon as you convert the return value to a single (higher dimensional) array (here done with `np.stack`), the data is copied.

Comment: Having said that, your suggestion does what was asked, so +1 :)

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Yes, that is correct. What I meant is that there are no additional intermediate arrays created (I was assuming the memory of the result was implied). But your clarification is correct, thanks.